# php artisan queue:work or listen not working Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have installed laravel 5.4 and want to confirm user registration, by email with queue, jobs table is created successfully, data are inserted as well in table user, but it outputs nothing when I run **PHP artisan queue: work** command. 
and I received nothing in my gmail box
I've spent many hours to resolve it, but still not working. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks much.

Jobs/SendVerificationEmail Class:

```
    class SendVerificationEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
  protected $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $data = ['email_token' => $this->user->email_token];

        Mail::send('email.email', $data, function($message) {
            $message->subject('This mail send by Queue Laravel 5.4');
            $message->to($this->user->email);
        });
    }
}
```

Contoller/RegistrationController class:

```
 class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('register');
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        //create user
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->email_token = base64_encode($request->email);

        $user->save();
        dispatch(new SendVerificationEmail($user));

        return view('verification');

        //add role by default the new registred saved as a User Role
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());

        // redirect
        //return redirect('/posts');

        //login
        auth()->login($user);

    }
    public function verify($token)
    {
        $user = User::where('email_token',$token)->first();
        $user->verified = 1;
        if($user->save())
        {
            return view('emailconfirm',['user'=>$user]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tell it which queue to process?

Comment: where is the CODE ?

Comment: Show an example of how you queued the job

Comment: I use queue database

Comment: Whats the queue name you're using? its stored in the queue column of your jobs table. If your queue name is `default` for example and your connection is `database` then run `artisan queue:work database --queue=default` to start processing jobs

Comment: I check my table jobe and I found that the queue is named default, I execute the command in cmd but it remains the same problem

Comment: what queue back-end are you using, check `config/queue.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of your SendVerificationEmail job set the connection and which queue you wan't to use, for example,

```
   public function __construct($user)
   {
        $this->queue = 'default'; //choose a queue name
        $this->connection = 'database';
        $this->user = $user;
   }
```

Then to start processing these jobs use the artisan command

```
 artisan queue:work database --queue=default
```

Also, in your SendVerificationEmail job add the line `public $tries = 3;` at the top of the file, now after this number of tries the job goes on the failed jobs queue and you can check the contents of the exception which put it there.

Comment: I tried your proposition and it works, the table job is filled but I received nothing in my mailbox and no error appears

Comment: @toto01 Is your mail set up in the .env file? I'd try testing the  Mail::send independently to make sure its not a problem with the config. Just try sending a mail right from the controller without any queue to make sure its set up right. Make sure gmails not blocking them or dumping them in spam.

Comment: If the jobs are working correctly the jobs table should be empty as jobs are auto deleted after they successfully ran or moved to the failed_jobs table if anything went wrong.

Comment: Running the command php artisan queue:work with "database --queue=emails" arguments helped me. Thanks @DaveCarruthers

Answer (score 0):

well, if you are seeing nothing in after que:listen , and mail is being sent by normal mail fascade
you should add the following things in the .env
que_connection=database
queue_driver=database

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you stop listening to queue certainly than you have to use the artisan command

`php artisan queue:restart`